# Ajax post with multiple query not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have html with ajax and php file. I use native php with mysqli for database. in connection, I have sricpt that named is config.php . this script :

```html
<?php
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'student');
?>
```

And then I have html with ajax like this :

```js
$("form#form").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'student/action.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            if (data == 0) {
                alert('all data updated');
            } else {
                alert('failed');
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
    <form id='form'>
        <input type='hidden' name='type' value='new-data'>
        <input name='name' type='text'>
        <input name='class' type='text'>
        <input name='hobbies' type='text'>
        <button type='submit' name='submit'>Submit</button>
    </form>
</body>
```

in student/action.php script like this,

```html
<?
php require_once '../config/config.php'; 
switch ($_POST[ 'type']) {
    case "new-data": 
    $qry1=$db->query("INSERT INTO tableA SET id=NULL, name='$_POST[name]' "); 

    $qry2=$db->query("INSERT INTO tableB SET id=NULL, name='$_POST[class]' ");

    $qry3=$db->query("INSERT INTO tableC SET id=NULL, name='$_POST[hobbies]' ");

    if($qry1 && $qry2 && $qry3) {
        echo '1';
    } else {
        echo '2';
    }
    break;
} 
?>
```

nah,this apps on hosting and at here the connection not stable. so when I submit by click `submit`, it will post data to student/action.php. it must be insert all query ($qry1, $qry2, and $qry3), but if I had bad connection it only insert some query, not all. How to solve it. thanks

Comment: remove space from $ db

Comment: thanks for answered, all query have been successed if my connection is good, but if my connection is bad, it just successed some query. i want to a way, how to insert 3 query into one package. and if my connection is bad, it's not insert and if connection is good, this package query insert successed. Thanks

Comment: Strawberry gave you the keyword, go look it up.

Comment: i don't understand with did say, i newby in programming.. help help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, never use $_POST, $_GET, $_REQUEST directly in your query (because of SQL injection), alway use mysqli_real_escape_string :

```
$name=$db->mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
$class=$db->mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['class']);
$hobbies=$db->mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['hobbies']);
```

And don't forget quotes

If you want to make sure all request are executed or all fail use transaction (you need innodb storage engine);

```
$db->begin_transaction();

//Your queries…

$db->commit();
```

If one request fail all previous requests are rolled back. you can use $db->rollback(); to cancel all queries before a commit. See php doc for more infos.

Comment: thanks Neo, i will try that. it's look that i wish. cheer... BTW, i used prepared statment. what' the best ?

Comment: Prepared statement may speed up multiple same queries, but it's not transaction, use $db->begin_transaction(); and $db->commit(); with innodb/xtradb storage engine.